# write large files to disk in clojure

Tags: csv, clojure

I have a sql query that returns a large number of rows. I would like to save the results of the query into a csv file on the disk. However, because there are so many rows I run out of memory before all the rows can be aggregated by the sql query.

It looks like this, and it fails during the query part:

```
(-> query format-transformer csv-writer)
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out with some help from the #clojure irc channel. You'll need two libraries:

```
(ns myproj.example
  (:require [[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]
             [clojure.data.csv :as csv]]))
```

The trick is to process each row as it is returned, then discard it. The java jdbc library has the query function which provides this functionality using the `:row-fn` and `:result-set-fn` options.

```
(defn sql->csv  [title]
  (with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer (str title ".csv") :append true)]
   (sql/query ds (second query)
             :row-fn (fn [row]
                       (csv/write-csv w  [(mapv str (vals row))]))
             :result-set-fn dorun)))
```

The interesting parts are the `:row-fn` and the `:result-set-fn`.

The `:row-fn` is dispatched every time a row is returned from the query. Each row is a map in the form `{:column1 "data" :column2 "data2"}`. We change the map into something that write-csv can use (nested vectors) with this: `[(mapv str (:vals row)])`. Then write-csv appends it to the file you've given it.

The `:result-set-fn` is crucial for not blowing your heap. By setting it to `dorun` you tell it to discard the head as it is processed.

This particular implementation doesn't provide column headers, that is left as an exercise for the reader (mine is too embarrassingly hacky to post on a public forum).

Comment: I would assume that your `:row-fn` now opens and closes the file for each row. Worse, it has to scan to the end of the file for each line you're writing. I haven't tested it, but I assume this could be more efficient if you pull out the call to `with-open` to happen outside of `sql/query`. I also think that you actually want to set `:result-set-fn` and not `:row-set-fn`, according to the latest [docs](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/query). I guess the default `doall` for `:result-set-fn` kicks in just the same or you're using an older version.

Comment: @schaueho: Good point, thanks. I've tested the changes and it is faster inside the `with-open`. I tried just putting the `write-csv` function in the `:result-set-fn`, but that ended up returning as many nils as there were rows.